# Finding $n$ such that $n^2 + 2n + 2019$ is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What $n$ solves $n^2 + 2n + 2019$ for the expression to be a perfect square?

Comment: What's the source of this problem? The appearance of $2019$ makes this seem like it might be part of an on-going contest.

Comment: In standard form, the equation $n^2+2n+2019=0$ results, from the quadratic formula, with a negative discriminant $$n=\frac{-2±\sqrt{4-4*1*2019}}{2*1}$$

so any solution $n$ would be complex.

Answer (score 1):

$n^2+2n+2019=(n+1)^2+2018=m^2$ implies:
$$2018=m^2-(n+1)^2=(m-n-1)(m+n+1)=2\times 1009$$

Can you finish it?

Comment: No integers solutions?

Comment: Exactly. Therefore this expression is never a perfect square